# Cisco AnyConnect reconnect when start docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, anyconnect

I have a problem with Cisco AnyConnect on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I start docker container (with non host network driver) Cisco AnyConnect instantly reconnected.

After starting docker container, AnyConnect logging something like that:

`acvpnagent[928]: The entire VPN connection is being reconfigured.`

**UPD:** I started using [openconnect](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/index.html) and everything works like a charm.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @Dani yep, I started using openconnect instead of Cisco anyconnect

Comment: @liveisgood8 how do you get openconnect to support the web-based saml flow?

Comment: @RobAudenaerde I'm using [openconnect-sso](https://github.com/vlaci/openconnect-sso), maybe this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advice [here](https://www.sitecoregabe.com/2021/05/cisco-anyconnect-docker-networking-issues.html) which basically is to use OpenConnect instead of Cisco's AnyConnect and the reconnections stopped immediately. I've been using OpenConnect with Pop_OS 22.04 for around one month without any issue